# Angular 2 - ngFor-Iteration --> click-event doesn´t works on single Array-Entry of ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an Array with defined answers for a survey-question in data model in component.ts of relevant template.
The template rendering for a `<li>`-tag for each answer (in Array) with iteration of this Array via *ngFor-Directive works great.

Now I want to implement a click-event for toggle an active-state for **EACH** of this `<li>`-tags (multiple-choise answer).

The following markup makes all items of the Array (all answers) active, **NOT** only the single `li`-tag, which I have clicked. That's my problem,where  I am looking forward to solve it with the support of the community.

**HTML-template**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let answer of questions.quest_1.answers, let i=index;" (click)="isActive = !isActive" [ngClass]="{'active': isActive}">{{answer}}</li>
</ul>
```

**relevant component Code**

```
questions = {
 quest_1: {
 quest: 'my question...',
 answers: ['answer A', 'answer B', 'answer C', 'answer D'],
},}
```

for toggle:

```
isActive: boolean = false;
```

I tried to implement the index on click-event in HTML, but it doesn´t works too.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want for  `Implement a click-event for toggle an active-state for EACH of this <li>-tag` you need to modify you array setting a property active to every item for example:

```
questions = {
 quest_1: {
   quest: 'my question...',
   answers: [
     {text: 'answer A', active: false},
     {text: 'answer B', active: false},
     {text: 'answer C', active: false},
     {text: 'answer D', active: false}
   ],
 }
}
```

and for the html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let answer of questions.quest_1.answers, let i=index;" (click)="answer.active = !answer.active" [ngClass]="{'active': answer.active}">{{answer.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works great with this change in my data object!

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer is almost fine, but I would improve it a little bit. I guess that there will be **only one** correct answer, so it would be better to set to `active` only the clicked one, while the rest will remain `inactive`.

> `this.questions.quest_1.answers.forEach(v => v.active = false);`

**[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/55XmcXHDa80sUOkDe6Tg?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The actual challenge is a multiple choice answer, so that Martin´s Code match it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of selected / clicked id as a seperate component

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let answer of questions.quest_1.answers, let i=index;" (click)="toggleOptionsMenu(answer.id)" [class.show-more]="answer.id === selectedId">{{answer}}</li>
</ul> 

selectedId = null;
toggleOptionsMenu(id) {
  this.selectedId = id;
}
```